# How can I solve this error with my reverse_lazy function?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I get the following error when using a CreateView:

```py
NoReverseMatch at /campus/NG Waverley Central/create
Reverse for 'campus_page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['campus/(?P<campusid>[^/]+)/$']
```

I suspect is has something to do with the fact that I am passing **campusid** forward from my **CampusPage** view, and I do not know how to pass this **campusid** inside the reverse_lazy function.

My urls.py looks as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:campusid>/', views.CampusPage, name='campus_page'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('<str:campusid>/create', views.CreateStreamEvent.as_view(),name='create_streamevent'),
]
```

My views.py looks as follows:

```
def CampusPage(request, campusid):

    campusobj = CampusModel.objects.filter(campus_name=campusid)

    return render(request, 'campus/campus_page.html',{'campusid':campusid,'campusobj':campusobj})

class CreateStreamEvent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = StreamEvent
    fields = ['title','campus']
    template_name = 'campus/create_streamevent.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('campus_page')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        super(CreateStreamEvent, self).form_valid(form)
        return redirect('campus_page')
```

I dont know if it is necessary, but my models.py looks as follows:

```
class CampusModel(models.Model):
    campus_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.campus_name

class StreamEvent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    campus = models.ForeignKey(CampusModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    youtube_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    streamevent = models.ForeignKey(StreamEvent, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: please show your html files as well

Comment: What's is the name of your app, try solve it by using something like app_name:url_name instead of url_name

Answer (score 1):

In your view you write:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('campus_page')
```

But the url `campus_page` expects a keyword argument `campusid`. Instead of setting success_url override get_success_url:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class CreateStreamEvent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = StreamEvent
    fields = ['title','campus']
    template_name = 'campus/create_streamevent.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateStreamEvent, self).form_valid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('campus_page', kwargs={'campusid': self.kwargs.get('campusid')})
```